# xen hvm : no console

Tags: linux, xen, opnsense

I am trying to run opnsense as xen domU.
My host is debian 11 and xen boots as dom0 with this configuration :
dom0_mem=1G,max:1G dom0_max_vcpus=1

I am trying to boot on opnsense from iso with this file :

```
builder = "hvm"                           
name = "router"             
memory = 1024                         
vcpus = 2
serial='pty'
sdl=0
vnc=0                          
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/sda3,sda,w'
       , '/opt/iso/OPNsense-23.1-OpenSSL-dvd-amd64.iso,raw,xvdc,devtype=cdrom,r'         
       ]                                     
boot='cd'
```

-> xl create -c opnsense.cfg

The domU seems to boot (disk and CPU activity) but the console stays empty.
I tried to access to console with "xl console router" but the command returns :
"xenconcole: Could not lock /var/lock/xenconsole.14: Resource temporary unavailable."

Is there a special configuration for console in hvm mode ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does opnsense actually support a serial console automatically in its installer iso image?

You may want to double check, just to make sure serial console actually works in your environment, with an ordinary Linux distribution install iso image if there is serial output.

The posted domU.cfg looks correct to me, it works in my non-Debian, non-OPNsense environment.

Comment: Thanks ! It works now. The solution was to choose the serial version of opnsense.